# using async and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

```
    public async override void InitData()
    {
        _domainModel = new DomainModel()

        ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Start();
        _State = Getstate();
        await _domainModel.Load(_State, ProgressIndicatorViewModel); //returns a task
        ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState(_State); //returns void not a task!
        ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop();

        DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() => ImageSelectionViewModel.RefreshImages(_imageList));
    }
```

i would like to make the two methods (1.domaminModel.Load(), 2. UpdateState()) to run on the same thread one after the other. not on the UI thread.

how can i do this?

Comment: Not the point of the question, but `DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke` is not necessary since you are already on the UI thread. I'm surprised this even runs.

Comment: it is needed to refresh the observable collection. don't worry about it. runs perfactly

Comment: Is `UpdateState` also `async void`, same as `InitData`? Is there any reason you don't use `async Task`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Noseratio updateState is not async. just a function to update a property of a different viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i would like to make the two methods (1.domaminModel.Load(), 2.
>   UpdateState()) to run on the same thread one after the other. not on
>   the UI thread.

**Updated**, if you want only `_domainModel.Load` and `ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState` to run on a separate non-UI thread, then just do this:

```
public async override void InitData()
{
    _domainModel = new DomainModel()

    ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Start();
    _State = Getstate();
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    { 
        await _domainModel.Load(_State, ProgressIndicatorViewModel))
        ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState(_State); //returns void not a task!
    });
    ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop();

    ImageSelectionViewModel.RefreshImages(_imageList);
}
```

Note you do **not** need `DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke()` wrapper then.

---

If you want the rest of `InitData` after `_domainModel.Load` to run on a separate thread:

```
public async override void InitData()
{
    _domainModel = new DomainModel()

    ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Start();
    _State = Getstate();
    await Task.Run(() => _domainModel.Load(_State, 
        ProgressIndicatorViewModel)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState(_State); //returns void not a task!

    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop();
        ImageSelectionViewModel.RefreshImages(_imageList)
    });
}
```

Note that `Task.Run` will automatically unwrap the nested task (of `Task<Task<T>>`) for your here. Also, you'd probably need to move `ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop()` inside `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Depending on what's inside `_domainModel.Load`, you may not even need `Task.Run`:

```
await _domainModel.Load(_State, 
    ProgressIndicatorViewModel).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

One a side note, you should probably handle exceptions inside your `async void InitData` method. You won't be able to handle them outside it.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong, because you're executing the following lines in a same thread, [_domainModel.Load] & [ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState] & [ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop], but he want to have [_domainModel.Load] & [ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState] in a same thread. and the ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop(); should be called in caller thread. For example if a UI thread is a caller thread, and ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop() changes a UI, then your code will not be executed successfully.

Comment: @YasserMoradi, you might be right, although I don't understand why @Gilad needs `DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke` then. I think he wants to run the rest of the method on non-UI thread. I updated the answer to address both cases.

Comment: `Note that Task.Run will automatically unwrap the nested task (of Task<Task<T>>) for your here.` What does it mean?

Comment: It means it calls `Task.Unwrap()` if the lambda returns `Task`. You can read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Consider following codes:

```
public async void Sample()
{
     DoOne();
     await DoTwo();
     DoThree();
     Dispather.BeginInvoke(() => DoFour());
}
```

***DoOne*** Will not executed in **UI Thread** (!), its thread will be a thread that is a caller of  method ***Sample()*** named ***Caller Thread***

In most cases in client side the Caller thread is UI Thread, because most codes are invoked by user actions (such as mouse click), but it's not a fixed behavior.

***DoTwo*** will be executed in a separated thread, it's clear that it will not be executed in caller thread.

***DoThree*** will be executed in a Caller Thread

and ***DoFour*** will be executed at UI Thread, it does not matter that what's a caller thread.

So the comment of @usr is totally wrong.

To achieve your goal change your code as following:

```
public async override void InitData()
    {
        _domainModel = new DomainModel()

        ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Start();
        _State = Getstate();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
             _domainModel.Load(_State, ProgressIndicatorViewModel).ContinueWith(() => {
             ImageSelectionViewModel.UpdateState(_State); }); 
           };
        ProgressIndicatorViewModel.Stop();

        DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() => ImageSelectionViewModel.RefreshImages(_imageList));
    }
```

Comment: To make it work as you expect, you need call `Unwrap` on the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. That's because `ContinueWith` returns `Task`, so `Task.Factory.StartNew` will return `Task<Task>`, and you're not awaiting the inner task in your current version.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for your reply, Note that my answer is conceptual, it will not even build ! (-:

Comment: Conceptually, I think you'd need either `await await` or single `await` and `Unwrap` here, otherwise the code after `await` may continue before `UpdateState` has finished on another thread.